# JavaScript doesn't parse when mod-rewrited through a PHP file?

Tags: php, javascript, mod-rewrite

If I do the following (this is the actual/direct path to the JavaScript file):

```
<script href="http://localhost/tpl/blue/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

It works fine, and the JavaScript parses - as its meant too.

However I'm wanting to shorten the path to the JavaScript file (aswell as do some caching) which is why I'm rewriting all JavaScript files via .htaccess to cache.php (which handles the caching).

**The .htaccess contains the following:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^js/(.+?\.js)$ cache.php?file=$1 [NC] 
</IfModule>
```

**cache.php contains the following PHP code:**

```
<?php

if (extension_loaded('zlib')) {
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
}

$file = basename($_GET['file']);

if (file_exists("tpl/blue/js/".$file)) {
header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 3600) . ' GMT');

echo file_get_contents("tpl/blue/js/".$file);

}

?>
```

**and I'm calling the JavaScript file like so:**

```
<script href="http://localhost/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But doing that the JavaScript doesn't parse? (if I call the functions which are within functions.js later on in the page they don't work) - so theirs a problem either with cache.php or the rewrite rule? (because the file by itself works fine).

If I access the rewrited file-> http://localhost/js/functions.js directly it prints the JavaScript code, as any JavaScript file would - so I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong...

PS: *I've tried changing the mime/content-type to text/javascript, aswell as clearing the browser cache - but no luck.*

All help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Have you tried to trace the network traffic (or used e.g. Firebug) to see which HTTP-header is sent to the client? Maybe the `Content-Type: text/javascript` never reaches the client.

Comment: Well when I view the the rewrited file directly I can view all the JavaScript code, and when I click Tool -> Page Info (in FireFox), the HTTP-header is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution is ridiculus given your stated aims. Keep it simple.

> I'm wanting to shorten the path to the
>   JavaScript file

Why? What's the problem with long paths?

> (aswell as do some caching)

Good aim. But have you seen mod_expires? Enable it then stick this in your .htaccess

```
 <IfModule mod_expires.c>
   ExpiresActive on
   ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 days"
  </IfModule>
```

Done.

And also, Apache serving a static file is so so much faster than apache starting up an entire PHP process which then serves a static file, not to mention (as you are finding out) less error prone.

Simplicity rules!

Answer (score 0):

The content-type should be `text/javascript`, not `application/javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to send the correct content-type header from cache.php, e.g. with

```
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
```

This is required because your webserver thinks he's serving a PHP script and by configuration it's told that the default output of such a script is text/html or text/plain. Therefore it adds one of these content-types unless you send one yourself from the script.

Comment: @Newbtophp: Is your error_reporting set to print errors like "unable to send header, output already started"? Which content-type is received by your browser? Is it the same you receive when you open the JS files directly (and your browser behaves right)?